# select all elements that parents do not have a certain class

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a functionality for close all/ open all is this type of [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

So my html goes like this:

```
<tr class="even shown">
    <td class="details-control"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd" >
    <td class="details-control"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" >
    <td class="details-control"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd shown" >
    <td class="details-control"></td>
</tr>
```

I have managed to implement the close all functionality using:

```
$('.shown').find('.details-control').click();
```

But cant get to find a solution for the open all functionality (Note that in the html the first and last td have a parent with class shown). I know that's probably very simple but I am stuck...

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem you have?

Comment: when i open an item individually, I add the class shown to the td so it shows a certain bg-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp):

```
$('tr:not(.shown)').find('.details-control').click();
```